# HTTP Request works in web, but fails on mobile? (Yodlee API)

Tags: android, rest, http, yodlee

Making requests to Yodlees Fastlink API, specifically to the [Fastlink Sandbox Environment](https://developer.yodlee.com/Fastlink_2.0/FastLink_Integration_Guide_for_Web).  The endpoint in question is the following:

`https://node.developer.yodlee.com/authenticate/restserver/`

We pass the appropriate params:

```
rsession:XXXXXXXXXXXXX
app:10003600
redirectReq:true
token:XXXXXXXXXXXXX
extraParams:
```

And recieve the following successful HTML response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Fast Link</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/v5/combo?/brands/default/css/scss/loader.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/finapp/10003600/?brand=XXXXXXXX&amp;id=10003600&amp;appId=XXXXXXXX&amp;channelId=-1&amp;version=1010.45&amp;status=published&amp;c=csit_key_0:XXXXXX=&amp;finappCDNURL=&amp;resturl=httpsXX.XX.XX.XX%2Fservices%2Fsrest%2Frestserver&amp;l=" method="post" id='form'>
            <input type='hidden' name ='rdata' value ='XXXXXX' />
            <input type='hidden' name ='capp' value ='restserver' />
            <input type='hidden' name ='userId' value ='XXXXXXXXX' />
            <input type='hidden' name ='firmId' value ='' />
        </form>
        <div class="inline-spinner"></div>
        <script>
function getCookie(k){var v=document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?'+k+'=([^;]*)(;|$)');return v?v[2]:false};
    var error = false;
    var isCookieSupported = getCookie('isCookie');
    var whichBrowser = "CHROME";
    if (typeof isCookieSupported != 'undefined' && !isCookieSupported){
        try{
            sessionStorage.setItem("rdata", "XXXXXXXX");
            sessionStorage.setItem('prefs', '{&quot;currencyCode&quot;:&quot;USD&quot;,&quot;dateFormat&quot;:&quot;MM/dd/yyyy&quot;,&quot;timeZone&quot;:&quot;PST&quot;,&quot;decimalSeparator&quot;:&quot;.&quot;,&quot;groupingSeparator&quot;:&quot;,&quot;,&quot;groupPattern&quot;:&quot;###,##0.##&quot;,&quot;groupSize&quot;:0,&quot;currencyNotation&quot;:&quot;SYMBOL&quot;,&quot;locale&quot;:&quot;en_US&quot;,&quot;segmentId&quot;:&quot;-1&quot;}');
        }
        catch(e){
            var isOLB = ""
            var ssoDomain = ""
            var postSource = ""
            var query = 'brand=' + XXXXXXX +'&app='+ 10003600 + '&appId=' + 'XXXXXX' + '&cookieDisabled=true' 
                        + '&version=' + '1010.45' +'&status=' + 'published';

            if (isOLB !=""){
                query= query + '&isOLB=true';
            }

            if (ssoDomain !=""){
                query= query + '&ssoDomain=' + ssoDomain;
            }     
            if (postSource !=""){
                query= query + '&postSource=' + postSource;
            }
            window.location.href='/apperror/?' + query;
            var error = true;
        } 
    }
    //sessionStorage.setItem("capp", "restserver");
    if (!error){
        document.getElementById("form").submit();
    }
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However when we make the *exact same request* from an android app REST client, it times out.  The response takes less than 500ms on the desktop client.

**What is happening differently between the two platforms?**

Comment: How does the HTTP conversation look like exactly in both cases? Maybe there are some differences. It might also be something in between your Android device and the target server (router/corpoproxy/firewall?). Are you testing in exactly the same network configuration?

Answer (score 0):

We recommend you to launch FastLink[FL] with the help of HTML form, In the sample HTML form(below) you need to update with the latest rsession and token values and launch FL2.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Invoke FastLink 2.0</title>
<body>

<table>
<form action="https://node.developer.yodlee.com/authenticate/restserver/" method="POST">
 <tr>
  <td>FinAppId's</td>
  <td>::</td> 
  <td> <input type="text" name="app" value="10003600" /> </td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>UserSession</td>
  <td>::</td> 
  <td> <input type="text" name="rsession" value="XXXXXXXXXXXX"/> </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>Access Token</td>
  <td>::</td> 
  <td> <input type="text" name="token" value="XXXXXXXXXXXX"/> </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>RedirectReq</td>
  <td>::</td> 
  <td> <input type="text" name="redirectReq" value="true"/> </td>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td>Extra Params</td>
  <td>::</td> 
  <td> <input type='text' name='extraParams' value='callback=http://www.google.co.in/'/> </td>
 </tr>  
</table>
 
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```